# Updating a table using JOIN by calculating result from multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-update

I have two tables as below:

`ObjName` and `RptName` is a composite key.

**Table 1:**

```
 ObjName | RptName | FileName | Success
 ----------------------------------------
 obj1    | rept1   | file1.csv| NULL
```

Table 2:

```
FileName  | Success
-------------------
file1.csv | 1
file1.csv | 0
file1.csv | 0
```

Table 2 can have multiple entries, like above.

The tables have to be joined on `FileName`.

I want to update the TABLE 1's `Success` column depending on below condition:

If any of the entry in resultset (got after joining tables) has the `Success` value as "1" then the `SUCCESS` column of table 1 should be updated as "1". Otherwise it should be set to "0".

Please help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @deterministicFail SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.Success = COALESCE(b.Success, 0) 
FROM table1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.FileName = b.FileName AND b.Success = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 
set success = 
  case 
    when exists (select * from t2 where FileName = t1.FileName and Success = 1) then 1 
    else 0 
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes from the join you can achieve it easily please try to do this way, hopefully this will solve your problem :)

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET 
    Sucess = 1
WHERE
    EXISTS
         (
             SELECT 
                 1 
             FROM
                 TABLE2 t2
                 LEFT JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t1.FileNmae  = t2.FileName
                 AND t2.successvalue = 1
          )
```